# How to share audio on zoom without pulseaudio in 22.10

Tags: pulseaudio

I need to be able to share streaming video in Zoom meetings. When I go to share I get the message "You need to install Pulse Audio (1.0 and above) to support Audio Share"

I just upgraded to 22.10.

Zoom version: 5.12.2 (4816)

While I understand that linux has moved to PipeWire, is there some way to install Pulse Audio so I can get audio in a share of a zoom meeting?

Comment: Somebody was successful at https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=151846

Comment: Thanks, user535733. Got me going in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

On my fresh (today) upgrade to 22.10, pipewire was installed and pulseaudio was not - nor was pipewire configured properly to provide pulseaudio services. Following the directions in https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/ I could see that pipewire was at least partly installed. I got wireplumber installed and then everything works.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to reboot (on Xubuntu 22.10), but after reboot it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I went through 30 days of Zoom's tech support to resolve this symptom on my system.
Seriously, it took them 30 days. However, they were nice the whole time, and escalated it all the way to their "Backend team".

The solution was simply:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y pulseaudio-utils
```

This was, on my 23.04 system, after ascertaining that both pipewire and pipewire-pulse were installed and running, via

```
ps -ef|grep pipe
```